# How to use bash script's if-else condition with just one command in kubernetes exec mode?

Tags: bash, kubernetes

How to use the bash script's if-else condition with just one command in Kubernetes exec mode?

Below is the sample bash script which works well trying to check a VM's connectivity to a remote server

```
 if ! nc -z -w10 prod.example.com 5671  > /dev/null 2>&1; then
      echo "Example.com Rabbitmq SSL Port 5671 is  not reachable from this Location/Resource!!"
      echo "Please Make Sure Example.com Rabbitmq SSL Port 5671 is  allowed in Your Firewall settings in the outbound Request!!"
      exit 1
else
      echo "Example.com Rabbitmq SSL Port 5671 is reachable from this Location/Resource!!"
fi
```

So how can we do this entire bash script stuff in just one Kubernetes exec command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'll be messy and not very readable, so my recommendation is to put this bash script inside a file on the image if possible, then you can use

```bash
kubectl exec -it -n {namespace} {pod} -- bash {path/to/script}
```

Otherwise you could do something like this:

```bash
kubectl exec -it -n {namespace} {pod} -- bash -c 'echo Check running on host $(hostname); if [ ! $(nc -z -w10 prod.example.com 5671  > /dev/null 2>&1) ]; then echo "Example.com Rabbitmq SSL Port 5671 is not reachable from this Location/Resource!!"; echo "Please Make Sure Example.com Rabbitmq SSL Port 5671 is  allowed in Your Firewall settings in the outbound Request!!"; exit 1; else echo "Example.com Rabbitmq SSL Port 5671 is reachable from this Location/Resource!!";fi '
```

This gives output like this:

```
Check running on host shell-pod
Example.com Rabbitmq SSL Port 5671 is not reachable from this Location/Resource!!
Please Make Sure Example.com Rabbitmq SSL Port 5671 is  allowed in Your Firewall settings in the outbound Request!!
command terminated with exit code 1
```